# Конфигурация exim для виртуальных хостов

Tags: exim

На linux сервере поднято порядка 10 виртуальных хостов(Apache). Например, example1.com, example2.com, example3.com. Пользователи, используя свои приложения, отправляют письма через exim. Необходимо наконфигурить exim так, что-бы пользователи хоста example1.com отправляли почту только через smtp.google. Все остальное без изменений.

Comment: а как `exim` должен идентифицировать эти письма?

Comment: Как я понимаю по доменному имени. Если письмо отправляется с адреса user1@example1.com, то оно должно маршрутизироваться на smtp. Можно ли вообще это сделать?

Comment: Смотря как настроен Апач и как там сайты отправляют почту. Например можно задавать разных отправителей для php или поднять несколько алиасов на виртуальном сетевом интерфейсе и натравить на каждый из них Exim, а внутри него маршрутизировать в зависимости от входящего адреса

Comment: *Можно ли вообще это сделать?* — можно. но нужна определённость. какой из стандартных заголовков анализировать? [From, Sender, Reply-To, Resent-From, Resent-Sender, Resent-Reply-To](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4021)?

Comment: Ну хорошо, допустим будем анализировать заголовок From. Я так думаю, что нужно как-то настроить exim router?

Comment: Можно ли использовать route_list для этих целей?

Comment: насколько я понимаю, вам нужен *route* с `senders=*@examlpe1.com` и транспортом через *smarthost*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на примере *debian*-овского пакет *exim4*.

где-нибудь в начале секции *router*-ов надо добавить новый *router* (имя файла (после цифр) и *router*-а — произвольные):

```
$ cat /etc/exim4/conf.d/router/100_test-smart
smarthost_for_example1_com:
driver = manualroute
domains = ! +local_domains
senders = *@example1.com
transport = remote_smtp_smarthost
route_list = * smtp.gmail.com
```

после внесения исправлений надо их применить:

```
$ sudo update-exim4.conf
```

---

проверяем, как будет отправляться почта.

от пользователя `user@example2.com` она пойдёт, как и обычно, через соответствующий *smtp*, определяемый *dnslookup*-ом:

```
$ sudo exim -f user@example2.com -bt user@ya.ru
R: dnslookup for user@ya.ru
user@ya.ru
  router = dnslookup, transport = remote_smtp
  host mx.yandex.ru [2a02:6b8::89]   MX=10
  host mx.yandex.ru [77.88.21.89]    MX=10
  host mx.yandex.ru [93.158.134.89]  MX=10
  host mx.yandex.ru [87.250.250.89]  MX=10
  host mx.yandex.ru [213.180.193.89] MX=10
  host mx.yandex.ru [213.180.204.89] MX=10
```

а от пользователя `user@example1.com` она будет отправлена *google*-вскому *smtp*:

```
$ sudo exim -f user@example1.com -bt user@ya.ru
user@ya.ru
  router = smarthost_for_example1_com, transport = remote_smtp_smarthost
  host gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com [2a00:1450:4010:c05::6d] 
  host gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com [173.194.220.109]        
  host gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com [173.194.220.108]
```

---

понятно, что *google*-вский сервер (в данном случае) «пошлёт» такое письмо куда угодно, только не по адресу `user@ya.ru`, но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, Александр! Вы мне очень помогли.